# Fetching all the notes from iCloud login user.

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud-api

Please help me if anybody have any idea about fectching all notes from iCloud. I am using below examples
[iCloud integration](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1)

[AppCoda iCloud Programming](http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/)

but in above examples they are creating new notes and fetching them. In my case I need all notes of login user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got answer of my own question. After alot searching I got solution that its built in feature in iOS 8.
[implementing iOS 8 Document Picker](https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/implementing-ios-8-document-pickers/)